# Exporting MYSQL Favorites to New PC

Tags: mysql, export, favorites

I just received a new upgraded work pc and my old ones has all of my saved/favorites mysql reports. I need to transfer them from the old pc to the new one.  Is there any way to easily do this?

We have attempted to do a Save Session and upload the file to the new PC along with exporting the connection from the old PC and importing (via tools dropdown) to the new PC and neither pulled in my extensive list of favorites.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have favorites. This sounds like a feature of a particular query application you're using.

Comment: Looks like  it's called SQLyog